# How to get the final HTML by running <script> tag in java

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am fetching the HTML contents of a URL. But there is a difference between HTML present in Inspect Source option of the browser and the HTML content I am getting in my JAVA code.

This probably is because of the unrendered `<Script>` tag of HTML file.
So my question is after getting the HTML content in JAVA using HTTPGET, how can I run the initial HTML to get resulting one( which contains the result of executing the `<script>` tag in it).

There is actually a Script written in HTML file which generates `<svg>` tag, which I am not getting when I am fetching the HTML file.
Any sample code to begin would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render JavaScript and HTML in (any) Java Program (Access rendered DOM Tree)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161051/render-javascript-and-html-in-any-java-program-access-rendered-dom-tree)

Comment: You have to use a browser. HtmlUnit may work; its JavaScript support is limited, but it's the easiest to script.